# What is the proper way to backup an ESRI File Geodatabase that is published to ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase

I have an ESRI file geodatabase (v10) that is published to an arcgis server map service. When the service is running, the fGDB is locked. Do I need to stop the service to get a clean backup? Or, is there a way to perform a backup through an arcpy script or through Catalog? I'm currently using Windows robocopy to transfer the fGDB to a backup drive. Here's the output showing the locked files:

```
 New File           0 Bikepaths.CFP0026.4968.5140.sr.lock
 New File           0 BuildingFootprints.CFP0026.4968.5140.sr.lock
```

etc, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any server should have a shadow drive. You can use the 'shadow drive' to **compact** the file geodatabase and that will remove the .lock files and re-order the file in the most efficient way. Then you can back this file up.
Here is a good couple good starting points:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/File_geodatabases_compressing_vs_compacting/003n0000007r000000/

Note:
Shadow drive has another name of disk mirroring

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_mirroring

Comment: Ah, I always assumed compacting was for sde geodatabases. Thanks!

Comment: I manage several servers and none of them have shadow or mirrored drives, although they do have redundant disks (RAID5, Drobo) and can survive the failure of one or more drives without data loss. Anyhow that objection aside, I copy the fgdb's with `xcopy` (or [xxcopy](http://xxcopy.com)), skipping the failures, and then compact the result. It's not the best solution as a feature class locked because of an edit session could get corrupted, but that's no different from a shadow/mirror drive.

Answer (score 2):

We have several high usage production web applications that run on FGDBs on the backend. The FGDBs get wiped out and rebuilt with fresh data nightly. We have a .NET console app I wrote that is based on [AGSSOM](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16293) that stops the services while the update process runs. Check out AGSSOM, it's pretty slick. Here's some of the C# I use to make a backup of the current FGDB before I blow it away:

```
// Only archive it FGDB already exists, if this is first run, then nothing to archive
            if (Directory.Exists(String.Concat(c.fgdbDir, @"\", kvp.Key[0], ".gdb")))
            {
                c.msg = String.Concat(Environment.NewLine, "Archiving data for ", kvp.Key[0], " - ",
                                      DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));
                Messaging.Log(c.msg, c.lw);
                // Create the FGDB folder in archive dir if not already there
                if (!Directory.Exists(String.Concat(c.fgdbArchiveDir, @"\", kvp.Key[0], ".gdb")))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(String.Concat(c.fgdbArchiveDir, @"\", kvp.Key[0], ".gdb"));
                    // Now copy from clips to archive
                    foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
                    {
                        fi.CopyTo(System.IO.Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
                    }
                }
            }
```

It just uses Directory.CreateDirectory and FileInfo.CopyTo to copy the FGDB - Windows sees the FGDB as just another folder. Works like a champ. Then, after the update process is complete, we start the services again using the AGSSOM-based application.

Comment: This was extremely valuable!